# List of object property not mapped while querying Azure Cosmos DB using EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm struggling with a problem while querying Cosmos DB using as ORM Entity Framework Core 3.1

My situation is this:

I have a class which has an ID and a List of objects (i can't show even the name of the models for internal security, so we'll call the first class Items):

```
public class Model
{
   public Guid DeviceId { get; set; }
   public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The class Items has different fields and as last field has a List of object:

```
public class Items
{
    //fields..
    public List<SubItem> SubItems {get; set;}
}

public class SubItem
{
    public int field1 { get; set; }

    public int field2 { get; set; }

    public string field3 { get; set; }

    public string field4 { get; set; }

    public double field5 { get; set; }
}
```

In my CosmosDB i've the following json that map the specific document:

```
{
    "DeviceId": "123456789",
    "Items": [
        {
            //fields...,
            "SubItems": [
                {
                    "field1": 1,
                    "field2": 6,
                    "field3": "blabla",
                    "field4": "blabla",
                    "field5": 100936000
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    ],
    "id": "blablabla"
}
```

Now, i have configured in my ApplicationDbContext all the owned entities and i have a line where i map this "relationship" as follow:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
{
  public DbSet<Model> Models{ get; set; }

  modelBuilder.HasDefaultContainer("Models");
  modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().ToContainer("Models");
  modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().HasKey(lr => lr.DeviceId);

  modelBuilder.Entity<Model>(lr =>
  {
     lr.HasNoDiscriminator();
            
     lr.OwnsMany(o => o.Items, na =>
     {
        na.OwnsMany(o => o.SubItems, na =>
        {
            na.ToJsonProperty("SubItems");
        });
     });
   });
}
```

And then in my repository, when i want to query the DB searching for a specific Device with a Device ID i call this simple method:

```
Model model = await _context.Models.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.DeviceId == deviceID);
```

Now the problem is that, inside the model ALL fields are mapped **except** for the `List<SubItems> SubItems`
and i've tried everything, i mean everything, but i always get null in return.

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advice

Comment: Can you also post how you created the tables? Maybe you didnt set the references correctly there

Comment: @NickPavini Sure, i've edited the post adding the DbSet and the container configuration